# Matlab, slope field, euler ODE system and 2nd order Runge-Kutta

Tags: matlab, system, ode, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I have system of differential equations

x' = ax - by

y' = bx + ay

I need to find approximate solution using explicit Euler method and second order Runge-Kutta, 
Conditions a = 0, b=1,

x(0) = 0, y(0) = 1, and accualy for more than that,

Using WolframAlpha, I determined exact solutions to this, and tried to implement algorithms on my own. However, im not sure what im doing wrong, because they seem to be too much dependent on h parameter and N. Below, I post my matlab code. I don't like the way my approximate solution is shifted or too sparse/dense compared to exact solution. I have to play with parameters N and h too much to get something decent, and im not sure if this is correct. This code should run right away if someone would like to help me. Thank you!

```
close all
clear all
[x,y] = meshgrid(-4:0.5:4);
a = 0;
% Task 9.a)
for b=[1 0.5 0.1 0.05]
dx = a*x-b*y;
dy = b*x+a*y;
figure();
quiver(x,y,dx,dy);
end

% task b,c for Explicit Euler's 
a = 0;
b = 1;

N = 1000; % 
h = 0.0125

t = linspace(0,4*pi,N);
xa = []
ya = []
xa(1) = 0;
ya(1) = 1;
    xe = cos(t) - sin(t); % exact solutions 
    ye = sin(t) + cos(t);

for h=[0.1 0.05 0.025 0.0125]    
    for k=1:N-1    
        xa(k+1) = xa(k) + h*(a*xa(k) - b*ya(k));
        ya(k+1) = ya(k) + h*(b*xa(k) + a*ya(k));   
    end

figure()
plot(xa);
hold on
plot(ya);
hold on
plot(xe,'r');
hold on
plot(ye,'b');

end


% runge-kutta
xa_rk = []
ya_rk = []
a = 0;
b = 1;

xa_rk(1) = 0
ya_rk(1) = 1
for h=[0.05 0.025 0.0125 0.005 0.0025 0.001]    
    for k=2:N-1    
        K1_1=  a*xa_rk(k-1) - b*ya_rk(k-1);
        K2_1 = b*xa_rk(k-1) + a*ya_rk(k-1);

        xintmid = xa_rk(k-1) + K1_1* h/2; % K2        
        yintmid = ya_rk(k-1) + K2_1* h/2; % K2

        K1_2 = a*xintmid - b*yintmid;
        K2_2 = b*xintmid + a*yintmid;

        xa_rk(k) = xa_rk(k-1) + h*(K1_1+K1_2)/2;
        ya_rk(k) = ya_rk(k-1) + h*(K2_1+K2_2)/2;

    end

figure()
plot(xa_rk);
hold on
plot(ya_rk);
hold on
plot(xe,'r');
hold on
plot(ye,'b');

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

#### The exact solution is incorrect

Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20x%27%3D-y,%20y%27%3Dx%20,%20x(0)%3D0,%20y(0)%3D1), the exact solution is:

[image: foo+bar]

#### The plot domains are incorrect:

In the exact solution, your domain is `[0,4*pi]` with 1000 points in between.

In the numerical solutions, you are using different values of **`h`**, without changing the number of iterations. This means that the domain size is from 0 to **`h*N`**. This is incorrect. If you want to vary the value of **`h`**, you need to specify the number of iterations so that your last iteration is at the desired last point of the domain (`4*pi`, for example).

One way of doing this is to vary **`N`**, then compute **`h`** as:

```
h = 4*pi/N    # could be off-by-one ... I didn't check
```

This produces matching results between the exact and numerical solutions.